# How do I free a char* (string), then allocate more space for it?

Tags: c

I'm creating a program to execute user inputted bash commands using the `execvp` function. After executing each command, it should take another command and execute that one. For example:

```
bash$ ./prog ls -l
-rw-r--r--. 1 (info-placeholder) file1.txt

ls -l
-rw-r--r--. 1 (info-placeholder) file1.txt
```

For this, I need to be able to parse each of the user's input into a `char**`, since this is the `execvp` function: `execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]);`

So, I created this function to parse the user's input and place it in a dynamically allocated `char**` called `arg_list`, where `buff` is the buffer the program read into and `bytes` is the number of bytes the `read` function read.

```
void parse_input(char **arg_list, char *buff, int bytes) {
    char *word = malloc(128);
    int num_spaces = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i++) {
        if (buff[i] == ' ') {
            num_spaces++;
        } // if
    } // for
    arg_list = malloc((num_spaces) * sizeof(char *));
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < bytes; i++) {
        if (buff[i] != ' ' && buff[i] != (char) 0) {
            word[i] = buff[i];
        } else {
            word[i] = '\0';
            arg_list[j] = word;
            j++;
            free(word);
            word = malloc(128);
        } // else
    } // for
    free(word);
} // parse_input
```

After testing `ls -l` as user input, it appears that `word` is not being reset after being added to `arg_list`. I'm not sure how else I could add the user inputted words into the list, and why `word` is not being reset.

Edit:
I now realize how many errors there were in my code, and there probably are still many more, sorry. To keep this short, I've tried to fix my code based on yall's corrections, but I still can't seem to get it to work. Here it is:

```
void pars_input(char ***arg_list, char *buff, int bytes) {
    printf("Beginning to parse user input\n");
    int num_spaces = 0;
    bool is_white_space = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i++) {
        if (is_white_space && !isspace(buff[i])) {
            num_spaces++;
            is_white_space = false;
        } else if (!is_white_space && isspace(buff[i])) {
            is_white_space = true;
        } // else if
    } // for
    printf("Number of words: %d\n", num_spaces);

    (*arg_list) = malloc((num_spaces + 1) * sizeof(char *));
    is_white_space = true;
    for (int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; i < bytes; i++) {
        if (is_white_space && !isspace(buff[j])) {
            (*arg_list)[j][k] = '\0';
            printf("Word added: %s\n", (*arg_list)[j]);
            j++;
            k = 0;
        } // if
        else if (!is_white_space && isspace(buff[i])) {
            is_white_space = true;
            (*arg_list)[j][k] = buff[i];
            k++;
        } // else if
    } // for
} // parse_input
```

I cannot figure out how to add the word to the dynamically allocated `arg_list` without having a temporary word to which I add the chars from the `buff`.

Comment: What does "not being reset" mean? I see one problem, which is that you use `i` for the `word[i]` and `buff[i]` and so `buff[3]` goes into `word[3]` no matter what, even if it's the start of the word. And another problem which is that `ls -l` only has 1 space so you allocate 1 pointer even though it needs 2

Comment: You don't want to free the memory to which `word` points. It's also being pointed by `arg_list[j]`, which you're still using. Remove the first `free(word);`.

Comment: Re "*why `word` is not being reset.*", `malloc` doesn't initialize the memory. `calloc` does, but you don't need this.

Comment: Arguments are passed by value in C. If you want to pass a `char **` value back to the caller via a parameter, the parameter needs to have type `char ***` and the function needs to dereference it.  I.e. the parameter should be `char ***arg_list` and occurences of `arg_list` in current expressions in the code should be changed to `(*arg_list)`. Also, you need to allocate space for a null pointer at the end of the argument list. Also, you may have a fence-post error since you are counting spaces and not words. I.e. `ls -l` needs three pointers - one for `ls`, one for `-l` and one for a null ptr.

Comment: I understand, @IanAbbott and ikegami. However, I am still not able to fully implement my function. I'm going to edit my original question and place my updated code at the bottom. If ya'll have the time to take a look at it that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the updated code: (1) In the second `for` loop, `buff[j]` should be `buff[i]`. (2) Initializing `is_white_space` to `true` before the second `for` loop isn't always correct. It should depend on the first character (if any) of the input. (3) After the second `for` loop, `(*arg_list)[j]` should be set to `NULL` to terminate the argument list.

Answer (score 1):

The problems are numerous.

- You don't want to free the memory to which `word` points. It's also being pointed by `arg_list[ j ]`, which you're still using. Remove the first `free(word);`.
- The last word doesn't isn't terminated by a space, so it doesn't get added to `arg_list`.
- `word[i] = buff[i];` is obviously wrong for any but the first the word. It's also wrong for the first word if the input starts with a space.
- You allocate `num_spaces` elements, but there could be one more than that. For example, `a b c` has two spaces, but three words.
- You don't handle leading spaces.
- You don't handle multiple spaces in a row.
- You only consider spaces as word separators, excluding tabs for example.
- You take `arg_list` as an argument, but you replace its value without ever using it.
- You don't return the list to the caller. Changing `arg_list` has no effect on the caller since C passes by value.
- Returning `arg_list` to the caller isn't enough. The caller will also need some way of knowing how many elements are in the array. For example, this could be achieved by adding an additional element which is `NULL`, like `exec*` expects.

Comment: I appreciate, understand, and think I've corrrected all my errors which you have laid out, but I'm still not able to fully implement the code. Sorry to bother you, I'm just really struggling with this problem.